# Why are these two different QLinearGradients looking the same?

Tags: qt

Here is the TestCode:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QLinearGradient>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsView *w = new QGraphicsView();
    w->showMaximized();
    w->setScene(new QGraphicsScene());
    w->setSceneRect(0,0,w->width(),w->height());

    QPointF p1(0,0);
    QPointF p2(580,80);

    QPointF p3(0,40);
    QPointF p4(580,40);

    QColor c1("#aa55ff");
    QColor c2("#aaffff");

    QLinearGradient g1(p1,p2);
    g1.setColorAt(0,c1);
    g1.setColorAt(1,c2);
    QLinearGradient g2(p3,p4);
    g2.setColorAt(0,c1);
    g2.setColorAt(1,c2);

    QGraphicsRectItem *r1 = w->scene()->addRect(0,0,580,80,QPen(),QBrush(g1));
    QGraphicsRectItem *r2 = w->scene()->addRect(0,0,580,80,QPen(),QBrush(g2));
    r2->setPos(0,90);

    return a.exec();
}
```

The thing is g1 should be a diagonal looking gradient, while g2 should be a horizontal gradient.

But when run, both end up looking horizontal (like g2 should look). However g1 should be diagonal. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: The second one actually is a diagonal gradient, but the start/stop colors are so similar and the slope is so small that you can't see that it's diagonal. Try exaggerating some numbers in your testcase (for instance: make `QPoint p4(40, 80)`).

Comment: Yep. That was it. Thank you.